# Mysql Average For results

Tags: mysql, average

[image]

I am having two tables. First table is onlinetestresult, which has selectedanswer column. Second table which has correctanswer column. If you look at the above image, I have combined the two tables by qustionid key. In the above result I need another column which should show the (wronganswer/(wrongasnwer+correctanswer)) * 100

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: use an outer select as `select correctanswer,questionind,wronganswer,(wronganswer/(wrongasnwer+correctanswer)) * 100 as somename from ( select sum(...)....)x`

Comment: I just need to know how to display another column which should display (wronganswer/(wrongasnwer+correctanswer)) * 100, with the other results.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I tried this query, but it didnt work. select correctanswer,questionind,wronganswer,(wronganswer/(wrongasnwer+correctanswer)) * 100 as average from ( select
sum(IF(o.selectedAnswer = q.correctanswer, 1, 0)) as correctanswer,o.questionid,
sum(IF(o.selectedAnswer != q.correctanswer, 1, 0)) as wronganswer
from onlinetestresult o inner join onlinetestquestion q
on o.questionid = q.questionid group by o.questionid)

Comment: you need to provide an alias at the end `group by o.questionid)x` check I added `x`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Its saying "unknown column wronganswer in fieldlist"

Comment: check for spelling mistake, it should work.